# How to run queue consumers

Tags: media-images, message-queue, queue

I want to use the media gallery image optimization.I read in the doc that I have to tun the media.gallery.renditions.update.

I tried with the next command

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start media.gallery.renditions.update
```

But he finishes it, he just waits and nothing happens. There is another way to run the queue consumers or how optimize the images from wysiwyg folder? Thanks!

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/content-design/media/gallery/media-gallery-image-optimization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo mistake in cmd.**

```
Its : bin/magento queue:consumer:start media.gallery.renditions.update
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same behaviour aswell while trying to assign many products to a website.

Although after letting it run (with no visual progress) or something it executed the command successfully.

You can try to run the job "consumers_runner" with magerun (https://files.magerun.net/)

with the command

```
sys:cron:run consumers_runner
```

and try